# Bugcode USB during windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-installation

I'm trying to install windows 7 with a DVD (the pc is a toshiba satelite a200). During the installation proccess a blue screen flashes and stops the installation. The blue screen inticates an USB problem (Bugcode USB).

Can you give me any ideas on who to fix this problem?

I have allready tried to install a windows XP. T

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove all attached USB devices during setup

Comment: There is no usb device attached...

Comment: can you get the crash dump?

Comment: do you mean the technical information?

Comment: yes and the .dmp file if possible.

Comment: where can i find that and how can i get that? There is any operating system in the pc (I'm trying to intall one).

Comment: boot from a Linux Live CD and look for the .dmp files: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744583%28v=ws.10%29.aspx copy them to a USB thumb drive and upload them from a 2nd PC.

Comment: Here is the .dmp file https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zk187tk0ustltr/081013-29811-01.dmp

Comment: the dump is not useful. I only see you get a timeout issue: USBHUB_TRAP_FATAL_TIMEOUT but I don't have the correct PDBs to read the USB data.

Comment: what I need to to to get the right PDB? Do you have any ather idea how to fix the problem without the .dmp or the PDB files?

Comment: we can't get the correct PDB. MS doesn't publish private Debug symbols: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Phone the MS support, they have the required information.